# How to bring a web browser with .ipybn link opened in my Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have received a link with .ipynb  link. I am new to Python and Jupyter and I need to open the link to work on the details inside.

The link opens in my internet browser and I couldn't properly see the contents and bring it in to a Jupyter notebook.

Could anyone please give me a tip how to handle such links for Python/Jupyter?

Comment: You should search around for setting up a python environment with Jupyter. Basically you need to run Jupyter Notebook, then within jupyter browse to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to Vinzee's answer: jupyter notebook starts in your home folder and you can't move up from there; only down into subfolders.  Open jupyter to see what folder it starts in, and make sure that you put the .ipynb file in that folder or one of its subfolders.